# Build OpenCV with IPP vs IPP_A support

Tags: opencv, intel-ipp

I build OpenCV 3.0, during CMake configuration, There are two options,

First, build with IPP support (WITH_IPP),

second build with IPP_A support (WITH_IPP_A)

What is the difference between IPP and IPP_A options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPP and IPP_A are not the same libraries.
IPP_A contains some functions for asynchronous processing and, as far as I known, it is a preview library.

Comment: IPP_A is not launched yet

Comment: Does IPP linked statically? Namely if I build with IPP on system A will it work on system B which doesn't have IPP?

Answer (score 2):

"IPP_A" stands for IPP Asynchronous. It was an experimental version of IPP and it was discontinued. Newer version of openCV does not have this flag, and does not use IPP asynchronous.

If you are using an older version of OpenCV ( < 3.4) you likely want to set this flag to off just to be safe. [Intel has discontinued all things related to IPP Asynch](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-integrated-performance-primitives/topic/762722)